# Where or Which Vedic Text's says "Vikriti Evam Prakriti"?

Tags: vedas, vedanta, identification-request, rig-veda

Herein [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homosexuality_in_India) it says:-

> Rigveda, one of the four canonical sacred texts of Hinduism says
>   Vikriti Evam Prakriti (Sanskrit: विकृतिः एवम्‌ प्रकृति, meaning what
>   seems unnatural is also natural),[14] which some scholars believe
>   recognises homosexual/transsexual dimensions of human life, like all
>   forms of universal diversities.

So where exactly is this sayings in the vedas?

Although I don't want correlate this with homosexuality, But for some other Philosophical Instance of Vedanta?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, neither the word *[vikṛti](http://meluhha.com/rv/find.pl?q=vikRti&lang=ved&acc=no)* nor the word *[prakṛti](http://meluhha.com/rv/find.pl?q=prakRti&lang=ved&acc=no)* occur in the Rig Veda.

Second, a phrase such as "vikṛtiH evam prakṛti" is most likely quoted out of context since, as quoted, it would mean "...change as well as natural state ...".

Not only does this does not mean "unnatural is also natural" but only means"change and natural state", it is also too general to be taken as a reference to homosexuality. You could appropriate this for any arbitrary purpose if you are bent on it.

Comment: [According to Nityānanda Miśra](https://twitter.com/MisraNityanand/status/1252860657310986245), ‘prakṛti’ occurs only thrice in Vedic texts. But in [another tweet](https://twitter.com/MisraNityanand/status/1252858187235000325) he too says the expression as a whole has no basis in the Vedas.